# Python Reverse the binary equivalent of input and output the integer equivalent of the reverse binary

Tags: python

Am supposed to capture user input as an integer, convert to a binary, reverse the binary equivalent and convert it to an integer.Am getting the right output but someone says the solution is wrong. Where is the problem?

```
x  = 0

while True:

    try:
        x = int(raw_input('input a decimal number \t'))


        if x in xrange(1,1000000001):

            y = bin(x)

            rev = y[2:]

        print("the reverse binary soln for the above is %d") %(int('0b'+rev[::-1],2))       
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("Please input an integer, that's not an integer")
        continue
```

Comment: If you are asking us to find an error in your code, then I'm afraid your question if off topic on Code Review. This is site is for reviewing code that you think is correct.

Comment: I think ist's correct since it gives the required output, I just want to know if there's something I can do to make it work better

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x  = 0
```

There is no point in doing this. You just replace it anyways

```
while True:

    try:
        x = int(raw_input('input a decimal number \t'))


        if x in xrange(1,1000000001):
```

Probably better to use `if 1 <= x <= 100000000001:` although I'm really not sure why you are doing this check. Also, you should probably explain to the user that you've reject the number.

```
            y = bin(x)

            rev = y[2:]
```

I'd use `reversed = bin(x)[:1::-1]` rather then splitting it out across the tree lines.

```
        print("the reverse binary soln for the above is %d") %(int('0b'+rev[::-1],2))
```

I'd convert the number before the print to seperate output from the actual math.

```
            break

    except ValueError:
        print("Please input an integer, that's not an integer")
        continue
```

This continue does nothing.